# I'm trying to open a class (FlappyBird.java) from the class (Starting.java) but i cant use "new game().setvisible(true)"

Tags: java, eclipse

I have these 2 classes. one is a game and the other is a menu class. My goal is to open a class (FlappyBird.java) from the class (Starting.java) but i cant use "new Flappybird().setVisible(true)" anyone knows how to fix this issue?

```
public class FlappyBird implements ActionListener, MouseListener, KeyListener {

public static FlappyBird flappybird;
int width=800,height=600;

public Renderer renderer;
public Rectangle bird;

public Random rand;

public ArrayList <Rectangle>columns;

public int ticks,yMotion;

public boolean gameOver,started;
public int score;


public FlappyBird() {

    renderer=new Renderer();
    rand=new Random();
    Timer timer=new Timer(20, this);

    JFrame jframe=new JFrame();
    jframe.add(renderer);
    jframe.setSize(width, height);
    jframe.setVisible(true);
    jframe.setResizable(false);
    jframe.setTitle("Flappy Bird");
    jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jframe.addMouseListener(this);
    jframe.addKeyListener(this);

    bird=new Rectangle(width/2-10,height/2-10,20,20);
    columns=new ArrayList<Rectangle>();


    addColumn(true);
    addColumn(true);


    timer.start();

}

public void addColumn(boolean start) {
    int space=300;
    int widthh=100;
    int heightt=50+rand.nextInt(300);

    if(start) {
        columns.add(new Rectangle(width+widthh+columns.size()*300,height-heightt-120,widthh,heightt));
        columns.add(new Rectangle(width+widthh+(columns.size()-1)*300,0,widthh,height-heightt-space));
    }else {
        columns.add(new Rectangle(columns.get(columns.size()-1).x+600,height-heightt-120,widthh,heightt));
        columns.add(new Rectangle(columns.get(columns.size()-1).x,0,widthh,height-heightt-space));
    }


}

public void paintColumn(Graphics g,Rectangle column) {
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN.darker());
    g.fillRect(column.x, column.y, column.width, column.height);
}

public void repaint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    g.setColor(Color.orange);
    g.fillRect(0, height-120, width, 130);

    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillRect(0, height-120, width, 20);

    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(bird.x, bird.y, bird.width, bird.height);

    for(Rectangle column: columns) {
        paintColumn(g,column);
    }

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.setFont(new Font("Ariel",1,100));
    if(gameOver) {
        g.drawString("Game Over", 100, height/2-50);
    }

    if(!started) {
        g.drawString("Click to Start", 100, height/2-50);
    }
    if(!gameOver && started) {
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(score), width/2-50, 100);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    flappybird=new FlappyBird();

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

    int speed=5;
    ticks++;

    if(started) {

    for(int i=0;i<columns.size();i++) {
        Rectangle rec = columns.get(i);
        rec.x-=speed;

    }

    if(ticks %2 == 0 && yMotion<15) {
        yMotion += 2;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<columns.size();i++) {
        Rectangle column=columns.get(i);
        if(column.x+column.width<0) {
            columns.remove(column);
            if(column.y==0) {
                addColumn(false);
            }

        }
    }

    bird.y+= yMotion;

    for(Rectangle column: columns) {
        if(column.y==0 && bird.x+bird.width/2 > column.x+column.width/2- 5 && bird.x+bird.width/2<column.x+column.width/2+5) {
            score++;
        }
        if(column.intersects(bird)) {
            gameOver=true;
            if(bird.x<=column.x) {
                bird.x=column.x-bird.width;
            }else {
                if(column.y !=0 ) {
                    bird.y=column.y-bird.height;
                }
            }

            bird.x=column.x-bird.width;
        }
    }
    if(bird.y > height-120 || bird.y<0 ||bird.y>475 ) {
        gameOver=true;
    }

    if(bird.y+yMotion >= height-120){
        bird.y=height-120-bird.height;
    }

    }
    renderer.repaint();

}

public void jump() {
    if(gameOver) {
        bird=new Rectangle(width/2-10,height/2-10,20,20);
        columns.clear();
        yMotion=0;
        score=0;


        addColumn(true);
        addColumn(true);
        gameOver=false;
    }
    if(!started) {
        started=true;
    }
    else if(!gameOver) {
        if(yMotion>0) {
            yMotion=0;
        }
        yMotion-=10;
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    jump();
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    if(arg0.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
        jump();
    }

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

This is Starting Class:

```
public class Starting extends JFrame{
    JLabel l = new JLabel("Name:");
    JTextField t= new JTextField(10);

    JButton start = new JButton("Start");
    JButton back = new JButton("Back");

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    public Starting() {
        p1.add(l);
        p1.add(t);
        p1.add(start);
        p1.add(back);

        this.add(p1);
        this.setTitle("Starting");
        this.setSize(300,300);


        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dispose();
                new FlappyBird().setVisible(true);
            }

        });

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Starting l = new Starting();

        l.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

}
```

The issue is that i can't type "new FlappyBird().setVisible(true);" can anyone fix that error?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Can you share the whole code of Game class?

Comment: That's a Game class, not FlappyBird

Answer (score 2):

your Game class does not implements any visual interface of java... add a "extends JFrame"

```
public class Game extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener, KeyListener { ... }
```

That will do the trick.

Comment: check my FlappyBird Class i dont want to use extends JFrame, is there a way to fix the issue with sticking with the same content.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible reasons:

- Check setVisible has the `public` modifier
- Check setVisible parameters count
- If the classes are in the same package check setVisible has protected or no modifier at all
- Let Game implements an interface offering the setVisible method
- Let Game extends a class offering a setVisible method without the private modifier
- Check the Game class imports the right classes
- ...

Answer (score 0):

You should also to separate UI with the functional logic btw..

I mean you should to have Game class just for a storing data, making operations, etc. and wanted data should be provided by visible methods to the class which is making the Game instance and just show them in according labels, etc.

Scheme can looks like:
`"Parent UI"` (with info labels, just UI components etc.) - `Game class` (controller for operations, statistics, etc.) - `Game instance data storage class` (player name eg.)

In this case you don't need to extend swing components (eg. JFrame)- either in Game class, either in instance data storage class, just in "viewer"- Parent UI in my case and you can provide data by controller methods.

> (UI can include instance of the game controller, and in game controller you can also make an instance of specific game)